# I am using Limilabs ftp component to download a specific file and get "Could Not get file size" error

Tags: ftp

I am in C# and using the [LimiLabs](https://www.limilabs.com/ftp)  component to download, I can and have used this for a long time without any issue. Now however I am encountering a problem in downloading a specific file from Monarchs server. I am asking is there anything I can do to work around this error or tell Limilabs, just download it (I can and have downloaded the file directly using Winscp) So I know I can download the file. But I need to automate this.

I couldnt post a code sample as the stupid UI interface wouldnt let me paste a totally valid piece of code as a code block the line it blows up on is the ftp.Download(RemotePath,LocalPath);

the ftp.Download throws an exception:-

Limilabs.FTP.Client.FtpResponseException was unhandled HResult=-2146233088
Message=Could not get file size. Source=Ftp

I have googled, and looked on the forum at LimiLabs... anybody have any indications of what this means is it something I need to configure in Limilabs, is there something I need to go and do with the ftp host of the files?

puzzled I couldn't find any references when doing google search

regards julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error: "Could not get file size", is raised by your FTP server.
It may indicated the file is broken, and the server can't access it.

You may try setting Ftp.DontGetFileSizeBeforeDownload to true in order to skip retrieving the file size before the download.

Comment: Well it transpires that the FTP site was broken. Thanks.